# How to fetch videos from Youtube channel in Angular 2 on Ionic 2 Framework?

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, youtube, ionic2

I am new to the Angular 2 and Ionic 2 so I am not getting the idea of how to fetch  and display video for my Angular 2 android App.

.component.js File

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
 private videoListArr = [];
 private title = [];
 private objArr;
 baseUrl: string = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/';
 private homes = [];
 constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, public navCtrl: NavController, private _homeService: HomeService) { }
 ngOnInit() {
 this._homeService.getHome()
  .subscribe(response =>this.homes.push(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response))),
  error => alert(error),
  () => {
    this.objArr = this.homes;
    this.objArr[0].items.forEach(element => {
      var url = element.snippet.resourceId.videoId;
      this.title.push(element.snippet.title);
      this.videoListArr.push({
        videoUrl: this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.baseUrl + url),
        videoTitle: element.snippet.title,
        videoDesc: element.snippet.description
      });

    });

  }
  )
 }

  }
```

Comment: Please add some code or whatever you have tried so far.

Comment: Try the Cordova YoutubeVideoPlayer with Jon Smart's additions: https://github.com/JonSmart/CordovaYoutubeVideoPlayer

Comment: I solved the issue Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<iframe>` to embed youtube videos in your app.

Say your youtube url is : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6KGPBflhiM

Your embed code will be:

`<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/a6KGPBflhiM" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

**Note:** You have to replace the url like I have done.

Also, please do a basic search before posting any questions. :)